# Angular - uib-typeahead add icon to every list item with separate ng-click option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I have a uib-typeahead where i have list of items. I would like to provide the user with the option to add particular value as favourite for that i need to show a star icon infront of every list item.

I need something like this.

[image]

How can I achieve a uib-typeahead list like this with option to add a favourite.

Only on clicking the star icon I will call an api to add as favourite, if the name is clicked only the value will be selected.

I have currently done this by having a pop-up when ever the user clicks an option asking whether it needs to be added as favourite.

**Edit:**

```
<input id="catg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text / Select" ng-model="addTolist" class="form-control" uib-typeahead="template as template.content for template in getTemplate($viewValue) | limitTo:8" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($viewValue)" typeahead-min-length="0" >


$scope.onSelect= function(value){
    var options = {
        title: '<b>Add as Favourite</b>',
        message:'',
        templateUrl: 'views/addFavourite.htm',
         size:'small',
         onEscape: true,
        buttons: {
            ok:{
                 label: " Enable",
                 className: "btn-primary fa fa-save",
                callback: function() {

             }
         }
}
$ngBootbox.customDialog(options);

};
```

Here in the callback I call the api to add as favourite

Comment: share verfiable code snippet with what you have tried so far

Comment: maybe [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/s7mWAtwdupP41GGO7dcZ/) will help

Comment: @tanmay I have added my code

Comment: @TonyRoczz Is it okay doing it in <ul><li> list??

Comment: @AlexisToby If the typeahead feature works then its fine with <ul><li>